# Какие из следующих высказываний являются отрицанием следующего утверждения?

Tags: алгоритм

Какие из следующих высказываний являются отрицанием следующего утверждения:

> Я пройду в третий тур олимпиады при условии правильного выполнения трех заданий
>   второго тура

1. Я не пройду в третий тур олимпиады при условии правильного выполнения трех
   заданий второго тура
2. Я пройду в третий тур олимпиады при условии неправильного выполнения трех
   заданий второго тура
3. Я не пройду в третий тур олимпиады при условии неправильного выполнения трех
   заданий второго тура
4. Я не выполню правильно три задания второго тура, но в третий тур олимпиады пройду
5. Я выполню правильно три задания второго тура, но в третий тур олимпиады не пройду
6. Я не выполню правильно три задания второго тура и в третий тур олимпиады не пройду

---

если я правильно понимаю можно ли составить отрицание импликации или же все проще просто по условиям просто подобрать?

Comment: Весь вопрос в том, как рассматривать основное утверждение - как импликацию, или как эквивалентность. Пройду ли я в третий тур **только** если выполню задания? А если выполню - **обязательно** ли я пройду в третий тур? От трактовки зависит и отрицание. А принцип построения отрицания - как у Fat-Zer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> если я правильно понимаю можно ли составить отрицание импликации или же все проще просто по условиям просто подобрать?

Да, всё верно:

- `A` — я выполню три задания
- `B` — я пройду в финал

Исходное условие является импликацией: `A ⇒ B`, что равносильно: `!A | B`. 
Отрицание этого выражения очевидно: `A & !B`, что по-русски звучит как:

«Я выполню три задания» и (но) «я **не**  пройду в финал». т.е. ответ `(5)`.

---

*В исходном варианте была ошибка. Спасибо @becouse за то что поправил.*

Comment: во первых нужно указать" Какие из следующих высказываний являются отрицанием следующего утверждения" -их должно быть несколько

Comment: во вторых я думаю что 6 и 3

Comment: @gaak2309, во-первых, не стоит цепляться к словам вопроса, а, во-вторых, ты не прав...

Comment: Вообще импликация не так записывается в стандартном базисе: A=>B=!A | B. Так что у вас ошибка.

Comment: @becouse так и какой ответ?

Comment: ! (A=>B) =! (!A v B) =A&!B ответ 5.

Comment: @becouse, спасибо за исправление, что-то пока жонглировал обозначениями пошло не так... а ещё меня что-то вторые мысли начали грызть по поводу условия (да, здесь есть каламбур): точно ли «при условии» — это импликация, а не равносильность... понятно, что форма «**только** при условии» была бы очевидно равносильностью, но и текущая как-то двояко звучит... правда в этом случае подходящего варианта ответа нет...

Comment: При условии то же самое что если... то. Если выполнено А то В

Comment: @becouse, мда... я что-то слишком много здесь думаю... пора спатеньки, видимо...

Comment: @becouse !A | B----что это обозначает?

Comment: @Fat-Zer !A | B----что это обозначает?

Comment: отрицание(А) или В

Comment: @becouse Тут ошибка. Если бы это была импликация, то можно было попасть в третий тур даже и не выполнив три задания.

Comment: @Fat-Zer Тут ошибка. Если бы это была импликация, то можно было попасть в третий тур даже и не выполнив три задания.

Comment: @gaak2309, я уже эти сомнения выше описал... ЗЫ: мне дублировать не обязательно — я и так получаю уведомление...

Comment: @gaak2309, возможно, тут действительно не прямая импликация, а обратная, т.е. в исходном высказывании подразумевается «если я прошёл в финал, то это значит, что я выполнил три задания» то ответ собственно будет (4)… а может подразумевается «если я выполню три задания, то мне гарантированно место в финале (хотя, возможно, у меня есть другие способы туда попасть)», тогда ответ (5)… а может тут вообще подразумевается равносильность: «чтобы попасть в финал мне необходимо и достаточно выполнить три задания», в этом случае ответом будет XOR, которого в вариантах нет… в общем я уже сам запутался…

Comment: @Fat-Zer А откуда Вы взяли обозначение в виде вертикальной черты и восклицательный знак?

Comment: @becouse А откуда Вы взяли обозначение в виде вертикальной черты и восклицательный знак?

Comment: @gaak2309, из Си (для восклицания, черта AFAIK использовалась и раньше), а оттуда они перекочевали во многие другие языки...

Answer (score 1):

Как я понимаю, есть 2 части предложения. К каждой части нужно сделать ровно наоборот, поэтому мой ответ 6. ( Я не выполню правильно три задания второго тура и в третий тур олимпиады не пройду )

Comment: а 3 вы не рассматриваете?

Comment: @gaak2309 Ведь он пройдет при условии правильного выполнения трёх заданий. Если хоть одно задание будет выполнено неправильно, то он не пройдет